# Work around for WebBrowser.Print() and IE's failure to pass webpage title (.NET)

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf, xslt

I am trying to batch print XML from a .NET application and automatically create files with the names the same as the webpage title. But IE refuses to pass the  of the html webpage to PFDCreator's autosave. It always ends up title as the URL. This isn't an issue when manually printing from Firefox, but visual studio uses an IE wrapper.  Any work-around suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

This is my current Print Sub:

```
''****************************************************************************

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim wb As New WebBrowser
        For Each file In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            wb.Navigate(file)
            Do Until wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop
            wb.Print()
       Next
        wb.Dispose()
   End If
    MsgBox("Printing Finished. " & FilesPrinted & " files printed")
End Sub

''****************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing a script to copy the files to a new location and changing their names manually. since IE passes the source filename this is sufficient for my uses.

Other FYI, this question was brought up on microsoft forums and seems to be another case of IE lacking:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/print-to-pdf-use-title-instead-of-url/b7578eae-b31a-4950-9db6-6cf845323d92?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/filenames-when-printing-to-a-pdf-driver/e5541ba9-d545-e011-9577-d485645a8348